# How to resolve git submodule conflict if submodule is not initialized

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have two branches `A` and `B`. Both contain a submodule (in the folder `sub`), however at different commits (which do not fast-forward from one to another).

```
A  B
| /
BASE
```

I've checked out `A`, but the submodule isn't initialized yet. Now I merge `B` and I get a conflict on the submodule.

```
$ git status
Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both modified:   sub
```

Issuing `git checkout --ours sub` does nothing (if the submodule is initialized it works, also `git checkout-index -f --stage=2 -- sub` does not work). `git add sub` causes the error `error: pathspec 'sub' did not match any file(s) known to git.`.

```
$ git diff sub
diff --cc sub
index 533da4e,ab2af77..0000000
--- a/sub
+++ b/sub
@@@ -1,1 -1,1 +1,1 @@@
- Subproject commit 533da4ea00703f4ad6d5518e1ce81d20261c40c0
 -Subproject commit ab2af775ec467ebb328a7374653f247920f258f3
++Subproject commit 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

`git submodule init -- sub` does nothing. Also `git submodule update --init --force -- sub` does not work: `Skipping unmerged submodule sub`.

So, how can I resolve this submodule conflict (without aborting the merge and retry after initializing the submodule)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

What makes your situation kind of annoying is that git won't let you initialize an unmerged submodule, so the ordinary advice of just setting the submodule to the state you want within the submodule then running `git add` won't work.  What you can do is to update the index directly, without going through the working tree.

One way to update the index is with `git reset`.  If you know a commit in which the submodule is in a state you want, you can use that.  For example, any of the following might be what you want:

```
git reset master -- sub
git reset master@{upstream} -- sub
git reset HEAD -- sub
git reset MERGE_HEAD -- sub
```

The other option is to update the index directly using the plumbing command `git update-index`.  To do that, you need to know that an object of type gitlink (i.e., directory entry in a parent repository that points to a submodule) is 0160000.  There's no way to figure that out from first principles, but you can figure it out from `git ls-files -s` or the following reference (see "1110 (gitlink)" under 4-bit object type): https://github.com/gitster/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/index-format.txt

To use that approach, figure out the hash you want to set the submodule to, then run, e.g.:

```
git update-index --cacheinfo 0160000,533da4ea00703f4ad6d5518e1ce81d20261c40c0,sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This works just like an ordinary merge: you have to supply the correct content at that path so git can commit it.  Submodule content is stored as its current commit id, so you have to add the submodule's path to project  (just like you add any file's path) when it has the right content, which here means its `HEAD` references the right commit. Usually you get that with an ordinary checkout.

In your case, you can't have both the correct merge result's content at the submodule path and no content at all.  The only thing *necessary* is to have a repo at that path with the right commit id in `HEAD`.  The containing repo really couldn't care less where the submodule repo at that path came from, the only thing that matters at this point is that commit id in `HEAD`.

Comment: Well "This works just like an ordinary merge", however `git checkout --ours` and `git add` doesn't work. How to "supply the correct content at that path"? - "The only thing necessary is to have a repo at that path with the right commit id in HEAD" - but how can I achieve that as initializing the submodule doesn't work?

Comment: A submodule is just a repo.  "The only thing necessary is to have a **repo** at that path".  `git clone u://r/l -b $yourbranch path/to/repo; git add path/to/repo; git commit -m done`.

Comment: This option worked for me. I simply cloned the right version of the missing repo in the submodule location and then the merge went through.